# Fastest way to sort multiple lists - Python

Tags: python, performance, list, sorting, zip

I have two lists, x and y, and I want to sort x and permute y by the permutation of x-sorting.
For example, given

```
x = [4, 2, 1, 3]
y = [40, 200, 1, 30]
```

I want to get

```
x_sorted = [1,2,3,4]
y_sorted = [1, 200, 30, 40]
```

As discussed in past questions, a simple way to solve this is

```
x_sorted, y_sorted = zip(*sorted(zip(x,y)))
```

Here is my question: What is the FASTEST way to do this?

---

I have three methods to do the task.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)
```

method 1:

```
x_sorted, y_sorted = zip(*sorted(zip(x,y))) #1.08 ms
```

method 2:

```
foo = zip(x,y)
foo.sort()
zip(*foo)       #1.05 ms
```

method 3;

```
ind = range(1000)
ind.sort(key=lambda i:x[i])
x_sorted = [x[i] for i in ind]
y_sorted = [y[i] for i in ind]  #934us
```

Is there a better method, which executes faster than above three methods?

---

Additional questions.

1. Why method 2 is not faster than method 1 though it uses sort method?
2. If I execute method 2 separately, it is faster. In IPython terminal,

I have

```
%timeit foo = zip(x,y)   #1000 loops, best of 3: 220 us per loop
%timeit foo.sort()       #10000 loops, best of 3: 78.9 us per loop
%timeit zip(*foo)        #10000 loops, best of 3: 73.8 us per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([4,2,1,3])
>>> y = np.array([40,200,1,30])
>>> order = np.argsort(x)
>>> x_sorted = x[order]
>>> y_sorted = y[order]
>>> x_sorted
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y_sorted
array([  1, 200,  30,  40])
```

---

```
>>> timeit('order = np.argsort(x); x_sorted = x[order]; y_sorted = y[order]', 'from __main__ import x, y, np', number=1000)
0.030632019043
```

**NOTE**

This makes sense if input data are already numpy arrays.

Comment: great, obvious winner here :)

Answer (score 5):

You're not timing this properly

```
%timeit foo.sort()
```

After the 1st loop, it's already sorted for the remainder. Timsort is very efficient for presorted lists.

I was a little surprised that @Roman's use of a key function was so much faster. You can improve on this further by using `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
ig0 = itemgetter(0)
zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=ig0))
```

This is about 9% faster than using a lambda function for lists of 1000 elements

Comment: great, checked your solution, it gives me 0.7580892901514744, +1 for you

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = [4, 2, 1, 3]
>>> y = [40, 200, 1, 30]    
>>> x_sorted, y_sorted = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda a:a[0]))
>>> x_sorted
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> y_sorted
(1, 200, 30, 40)
```

Performance:

```
>>> timeit('foo = zip(x,y); foo.sort(); zip(*foo)', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
1.0197240443760691
>>> timeit('zip(*sorted(zip(x,y)))', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
1.0106219310922597
>>> timeit('ind = range(1000); ind.sort(key=lambda i:x[i]); x_sorted = [x[i] for i in ind]; y_sorteds = [y[i] for i in ind]', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
0.9043525504607857
>>> timeit('zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda a:a[0]))', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
0.8288150863453723
```

To see the full picture:

```
>>> timeit('sorted(x)', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
0.40415491505723367            # just getting sorted list from x
>>> timeit('x.sort()', 'from __main__ import x, y', number=1000)
0.008009909448446706           # sort x inplace
```

@falsetru method - **fastest for np.arrays**

```
>>> timeit('order = np.argsort(x); x_sorted = x[order]; y_sorted = y[order]', 'from __main__ import x, y, np', number=1000)
0.05441799872323827
```

As @AshwiniChaudhary suggested in comments, **for lists** there's a way to speed it up by using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`:

```
>>> timeit('zip(*sorted(izip(x, y), key=itemgetter(0)))', 'from __main__ import x, y;from operator import itemgetter;from itertools import izip', number=1000)
0.4265049757161705
```

Comment: You can use `itertools.izip` for inner zip to make it memory efficient.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary checked :)

Comment: Don't use `izip` outside of sorted as it returns an iterator not list.

Comment: ok, but could it be useful if we need to get just y_sorted, like `y_sorted = [k[1] for k in izip(*sorted(izip(x, y), key=itemgetter(0)))]`?

Comment: But that way we can only get `y_sorted` not `x_Sorted`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes I mean could it be useful if we don't need x_sorted at all and just wanted to get y sorted?

Comment: You need `zip(*sorted(izip(x, y), key=itemgetter(0)))[1]` if you want just `y_sorted` or better `[z[1] for z in sorted(izip(x, y), key=itemgetter(0))]`. Note that the call to `itemgetter` can be removed if the items in x are unique.
`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is there a way to use the itertools.izip method to stop after the first N highest (or lowest) values have been found where N < len(x) or len(y)?